# Upgrade Android Support library to 24.2.0 makes my app crash

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button, android-support-design

My previous support library version is 24.1.1. The app works fine. But after upgrade to version 24.2.0, the app always force stop when start. My app's MainActivity contains a `BottomSheetBehavior` view and `FloatingActionButton`. Here's the error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$Behavior.isBottomSheet(FloatingActionButton.java:597)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$Behavior.onDependentViewChanged(FloatingActionButton.java:589)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$Behavior.onDependentViewChanged(FloatingActionButton.java:528)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.offsetChildToAnchor(CoordinatorLayout.java:1564)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onChildViewsChanged(CoordinatorLayout.java:1233)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$OnPreDrawListener.onPreDraw(CoordinatorLayout.java:1812)
...
...
```

Update: Here is my MainActivity's layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@id/appBar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:viewPagerTab="@{(currentFragment instanceof SongBookTabFragment)? viewPagerTab : null}" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="clickFAB"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="com.boombile.originalsong.ui.widget.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetPlayer"
        layout="@layout/view_bottom_sheet_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout?

Comment: @TinTran, please see my update.

Comment: is com.boombile.originalsong your package name? Can you also post com.boombile.originalsong.ui.widget.ScrollAwareFABBehavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is a bug, but currently with the **24.2.0** the FAB can not longer be anchored to indirect children of `CoordinatorLayout`.

The `layout_anchor` only **works with direct children** of `CoordinatorLayout`. You'll need to change your `layout_anchor` to use a different view.

You can check the source code of the `FloatingActionButton`:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child,
                View dependency) {
            if (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout) {
                // If we're depending on an AppBarLayout we will show/hide it automatically
                // if the FAB is anchored to the AppBarLayout
                updateFabVisibilityForAppBarLayout(parent, (AppBarLayout) dependency, child);
            } else if (isBottomSheet(dependency)) {
                updateFabVisibilityForBottomSheet(dependency, child);
            }
            return false;
        }

        private static boolean isBottomSheet(View view) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            return lp != null && lp.getBehavior() instanceof BottomSheetBehavior;
        }
```

More [details here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220250).

Comment: That's right. Thank you. Now I'm getting other new problems with this new version. :-/

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, please see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220250

You should upgrade to the 24.2.1 version, this issue got resolved there.